# Changed Document root is not working in xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, configuration-files, httpd.conf

I have followed a few answers that told me to change the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory`
This is my current `httpd.conf` for xampp 7.2.5

`ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"`

```
DocumentRoot "~/Code/php-xampp"
<Directory "~/Code/php-xampp">
    # comments removed for readability
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When is start the `Apache Web Server` from xampp gui interface, it gives the following error

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 229 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot '/opt/lampp/~/Code/php-xampp' is not a directory, or is not readable
```

Why is the `DocumentRoot` being appended to the `ServerRoot`, this was working before i restarted my computer.

Comment: Don't use ``~``. Use an absolute path. A ``~`` means nothing to Apache and it doesn't expand it to your user directory.

Comment: Ok I'll try that out

Comment: Using the absolute path worked.